# PHP: Undefined index in $_REQUEST when the data does exist

Tags: php, file-upload, request

I'm having a problem where data in the **$_REQUEST** array cannot be seen.

I have a form on a page which passes in some simple data and a file to upload. I have given the submit button a name of "*submitButton*" and a value of "*Click to upload*".

When I click the submit button, the file upload fails with a 1 error (even though the file size is well below the limits defined in php.ini), but I also recive notices for undefined indexes for the variables in **$_REQUEST** that are definitely there.

For example, I check to see if the button has been clicked with

```
if ($_REQUEST["submitButton"] && $_REQUEST["submitButton"] == "Click to upload")
```

This line issues an undefined index for "submitButton", yet if I

```
echo print_r($_REQUEST,true);
```

before and after the if statement, I can clearly see

```
Array ( [submitButton] => Click to upload, ....)
```

which contains "submitButton", it is defined and has data.

I think this is a setup problem as it was working but after a server reboot has stopped. I did change the script execution time and script size, but don't think much else. I have since put them back but still have the same problem. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: I have discovered the problem. There are 2 places that php.ini is set on the server and I was updating the wrong one. Therefore when I tried to upload a 2.5mb file, it was above the limit of 2mb in the unknown php.ini file. This in turn caused problems with the $_REQUEST data (has been documented elsewhere).

After setting the parameters in the correct php.ini file, everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_REQUEST["submitButton"] && $_REQUEST["submitButton"] == "Click to upload")
```

replace it with

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["submitButton"]) && $_REQUEST["submitButton"] == "Click to upload")
```

Comment: You are missing isset

Comment: It's nothing to do with isset, I could put that in the code and the problem would still exist, it just wouldn't report it. 

It is reporting the data is not set when it is. It is falsely reporting an undefined index, that is the problem.

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the size of the file I'm uploading. If I upload a much smaller file the page works as expected. Still don't understand why a 2.9mb file is causing issues when I've set a 10mb limit on the form (double checked server side) and have the following limits in php.ini

    `memory_limit = 384M`
    `post_max_size = 64M`

Also, the exact same image uploaded without problems before. Very strange!

Comment: have u change it upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot that one. That's set to 150M

Comment: share your code with us without it i am not able to help